# How to change System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton highlight/background color when checked?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0, toolstripbutton

I have a ToolStripButton that is used as a radio button. When it is checked, a blue outline surrounds the button, but there is no background color. It is not clear enough for the user that the button is checked, so I would like to change the background color to make the check state more visible.

How do I go about changing the highlight color when the Checked property is set to true?

Here is a code snippet:

```
this.hideInactiveVehiclesToolstripButton.CheckOnClick = true;
this.hideInactiveVehiclesToolstripButton.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
this.hideInactiveVehiclesToolstripButton.AutoSize = false;
this.hideInactiveVehiclesToolstripButton.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
this.hideInactiveVehiclesToolstripButton.Image = global::ClientUI.Properties.Resources.toggleInactive;
this.hideInactiveVehiclesToolstripButton.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
this.hideInactiveVehiclesToolstripButton.Name = "hideInactiveVehiclesToolstripButton";
this.hideInactiveVehiclesToolstripButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 48);
this.hideInactiveVehiclesToolstripButton.Text = "Hide Inactive Vehicles";
this.hideInactiveVehiclesToolstripButton.Click +=new System.EventHandler(this.hideInactiveVehiclesToolstripButton_Click);
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can provide your own tool strip renderer to draw the button's background the way you want them.  This example code gives the checked button a very visible black background:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        toolStrip1.Renderer = new MyRenderer();
    }
    private class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer {
        protected override void OnRenderButtonBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e) {
            var btn = e.Item as ToolStripButton;
            if (btn != null && btn.CheckOnClick && btn.Checked) {
                Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, e.Item.Size);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, bounds);
            }
            else base.OnRenderButtonBackground(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't like the size of the rectangle drawn from this example, you might want to use the ContentRectangle property of the button if you don't wish to override the background borders.

Answer (score 0):

on Event click for every toolStripButton

```
private void toolStripButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolStrip1.Items[0].BackColor = SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
            toolStrip1.Items[1].BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            toolStrip1.Items[2].BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            toolStrip1.Items[3].BackColor = SystemColors.Control;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the VB.net code

```
Public Class Form1

   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      toolStrip1.Renderer = New MyRenderer()
   End Sub

   Public Class MyRenderer
      Inherits ToolStripProfessionalRenderer

      Protected Overrides Sub OnRenderButtonBackground(ByVal e As ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs)
          Dim btn As ToolStripButton = e.Item
          If (Not IsDBNull(btn) And btn.CheckOnClick And btn.Checked) Then
              Dim bounds As Rectangle = New Rectangle(Point.Empty, e.Item.Size)
              e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, bounds)
          End If
      End Sub
End Class
```