# Change the color of the arrow near the menuitem in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, menuitem

I have an application that contains a lot of menuitems. I have changed the background of the menuitem into dark gray and the text into white but the arrow near the text is still black. I want to change the color of this arrow into white.

I've found the exlanation in this document:

[MenuItem.OwnerDraw Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.ownerdraw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

and a similar question on stackoverflow:

[Question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907940/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-check-mark-or-more-arrow-on-a-winforms-context-me)

It is possible to change the color of the arrow next to a menuitem in a easier way? (This is the arrow that allows you to display a submenu). I mean using something like ProfessionalColorTable.

Comment: No you need to draw the menu yourself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inspiration was this [very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097164/how-to-change-system-windows-forms-toolstripbutton-highlight-background-color-wh/2097341#2097341) by [@Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant). 
[image]
Provide a custom renderer for your menu strip on form load or constructor like:

```
this.menuStrip.Renderer = new WhiteArrowRenderer();
```

and override the arrow paint:

```
public class WhiteArrowRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer { 
    protected override void OnRenderArrow (ToolStripArrowRenderEventArgs e) { 
        var tsMenuItem = e.Item as ToolStripMenuItem;
        if (tsMenuItem != null)
            e.ArrowColor = Color.White;
        base.OnRenderArrow(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really useful. I tried it and it works. 
Unfortunately, this solution remove another change that I made. I used this code to override some methods to change some colors:                                    ToolStripProfessionalRenderer toolStripProfessionalRenderer = new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(new MyColorTable());      ToolStripManager.Renderer = toolStripProfessionalRenderer; With the new code I lose the old changes. How can I solve this? Thank you very much

Comment: Merge the existing color table to the custom renderer that can handle arrows too.

Comment: What do you mean? I've tryed to do this: CustomToolStripRenderer customRenderer = new ustomToolStripRenderer(new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(new MyColorTable()));     customRenderer.Render(); public void Render(){  
ToolStripManager.Renderer = _toolStripRenderer;
    }     protected override void OnRenderArrow(ToolStripArrowRenderEventArgs e){var tsMenuItem = e.Item as ToolStripMenuItem; if (tsMenuItem != null) e.ArrowColor = Color.White; base.OnRenderArrow(e);} and in this way the arrows remains black because  with ToolStripManager.Renderer = _toolStripRenderer I override the renderer.

Comment: Totally replace the existing `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer` with the custom `WhiteArrowRenderer`.Use the constructor that also customizes the color table. By merging I mean merging, 2 in 1. No offense, this is a totally different question. As far as I am concerned other conflicts in your app defeat the purpose of this question.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The initial question was correct but I noticed another problem after solving the initial question. I should post a new question, since the problem is different from the original one. I do it now since the last change you suggested to me, unfortunately, does not work. Thank you

Comment: The follow-up question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26614398/6674014). You need both for this to work.