# How to change the back color of tool strip split button in windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripbutton

How to change the back color of the tool strip split button in windows forms application.
Back color property not working.. This the code in designer class..

```
        this.level.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))));
        this.level.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
        this.level.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.autoToolStripMenuItem1,
        this.loadToolStripMenuItem1});
        this.level.Image = global::PACS.Properties.Resources.winlevel;
        this.level.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        this.level.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(1, 1, 1, 2);
        this.level.Name = "level";
        this.level.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 43);
        this.level.Text = "Level";
        this.level.TextImageRelation = System.Windows.Forms.TextImageRelation.Overlay;
        this.level.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Window_level_Paint);
        this.level.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Window_level_Click);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton highlight/background color when checked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097164/how-to-change-system-windows-forms-toolstripbutton-highlight-background-color-wh)

Comment: you can find the ansswer here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/54088322/5627499](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54088322/5627499)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's BackColor property did not work by default:
Accorthing this ([ToolStripSplitButton BackColor does not work](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/0a2d4936-d3d0-4212-b412-316c41ca45e5)), follow these two steps:

1) Set BackgroundImage to a valid image. It does not matter what. I use a 1 pixel x 1 pixel BMP as local resource.

2) Set BackgroundImageLayout to None. This is why it does not matter what image you use above.

Result:

[image]

Comment: That didn't have any effect in my case. The color of the dropdown didn't change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom renderer for the `toolstrip`, you can found a sample in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2097341/2651073) for a similar question.

Comment: **How?** Neither `ToolStripButton` nor `ToolStripSplitbutton` have a `Renderer` property. Only `MenuStrip` and `ToolStrip` have that. How would you assign the renderer mentioned in the link?