# What color is used when rendering a focused ToolStripItem by default?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Quite an idiot question, however, I wanted to place a custom control on a `ToolStrip` through a `ToolStripControlHost`.

```
var myControl = ...
//...
toolStrip.Items.Insert(0, new ToolStripControlHost(myControl));
```

But the default coloring differs on `ToolStrip` items and simple controls. On a `ToolStrip` they're colored blue when focused, while usual controls are grayed.

So I wanted to try to apply similar colors to my custom control.
In particular I use buttons with `FlatStyle` set to `Flat`. So I'd love to set `MouseOverBackColor` to the color used to render a hovered `ToolStripButton`.

Could anyone say, what that color is? Or how to apply the coloring scheme to a custom control nested into a `ToolStripControlHost` used to render regular `ToolStrip` items?

Comment: Use your own renderer and you should be fine.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2097341/2622467

Comment: @kloetpatra I do not want to change `ToolStrip` rendering. I want to change the rendering/coloring of the custom control